# Не получается корректно передать аргумент при запуске в контейнер

Tags: docker

Прохожу курс [Управление вычислениями](https://stepik.org/course/1612/). Вопрос по заданию:

> Вам требуется создать Dockerfile, в котором будет описано создание
>   образа со следующими свойствами:
>
> - При запуске контейнера из этого образа без аргументов он должен
>     вывести строку "Hello World!" и завершить работу
> - При запуске контейнера с аргументом < arg > должна быть выведена строка  "Hello < arg >!", после чего контейнер должен завершить свою работу
>
> Пример того, как должно работать решение:
>
> docker build -t test .
>
> docker run --rm test
>
> > Hello World!
>
> docker run --rm test Universe
>
> > Hello Universe!

Моё решение:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

LABEL maintainer="Egor Urvanov"

ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "Hello"]
CMD ["world!"]
```

Проблема в заключается в том, что при запуске контейнера из образа с аргументом, у меня не получается вывести

```
> Hello Universe!
```

Как можно поправить данную ошибку.

[Здесь](https://stepik.org/lesson/35907/step/8?course=%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8&discussion=433186&unit=15063) можно найти задание полность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переданные аргументы можно получить через $.

Ваш рабочий Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
LABEL maintainer="Egor Urvanov"
ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "Hello"]
CMD $1
```